# Collecting a Sparklyr Long Integer into an R Dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

How do you collect a Spark table into R using sparklyr while preserving long integers without having to convert them to strings beforehand?

My understanding is that R has an integer64 type that can be used to handle large integer values. Spark handles such values using its LongType but when I collect a Spark table with a Long I get a double on the R side. The issue with doubles is that they can lose precision.

I have attached an image to show the discrepancy that happens when collecting the data frame. If I convert the value into a string, it is collected perfectly. But if I don't, it turns into a double and then loses precision.

I was wondering if there were some Spark configs or some options I have to set somewhere to get sparklyr to collect it as an integer64.

[image: Long Integer Into R DataFrame Example Screenshot]

Comment: integer64 is provided by the bit64 package, i think? not native

Comment: As Calum said, the `integer64` package is your only hope. Other package use it, among them reticulate or our nanotime package for higher-precision timestamps.  It is imperfect and you have to be careful _but there simply is no `int64_t` in R_.

Comment: So, does that mean that this feature is lacking in sparklyr?